How to use jsonb_to_record and x() with sqlalchemy
I am trying to make the following SQL alchemy orm query work :
query = (
    sqlalchemy.select(
        cls.tasks_table.id.label("task_id"),
        cls.tasks_table.doc.label("task_doc"),
        cls.table.id.label("job_id"),
        cls.table.doc.label("job_doc"),
    )
    .select_from(
        func.jsonb_to_record(cls.tasks_table.doc).alias("x(job_id uuid)"),
    )
    .join(cls.table, func.jsonb_to_record(cls.tasks_table.doc), 'job_id' == cls.table.id)
)

yet this generates the following SQL query :
SELECT public.tasks.id AS task_id, public.tasks.doc AS task_doc, public.jobs.id AS job_id, public.jobs.doc AS job_doc 
FROM public.tasks, jsonb_to_record(public.tasks.doc) AS "x(job_id uuid)" 
JOIN public.jobs ON public.jobs.id = :id_1

The problem here are the apostrophes around x(job_id uuid). without it, the SQL query will be correct.
Any idea how to pass the x(job_id uuid) part while using jsonb_to_record ?
My goal is to use this column for joining another table later in the join_from clause.

Eventually I solved it with table_valued and render_derived :
query = (
    sqlalchemy.select(
        cls.tasks_table.id.label("task_id"),
        cls.tasks_table.doc.label("task_doc"),
        cls.table.id.label("job_id"),
        cls.table.doc.label("job_doc"),
    )
    .select_from(
        func.jsonb_to_record(cls.tasks_table.doc)
        .table_valued(sqlalchemy.column("job_id", UUID()))
        .render_derived(name="x", with_types=True)
        .alias("job_id"),
    )
    .join(
        cls.table,
        sqlalchemy.column("job_id", is_literal=True) == cls.table.id,
    )
)

